# How to create wrapped DOT asset on local setup

Tags: xcm, assets, astar, zombienet

Local setup: Zombienet running Shiden and Relay Chain.

What are the exact steps needed to create an asset which represents DOT on Shiden (wrapped DOT). More specifically, I am trying to create the same asset that is present on Shiden and Astar: `340,282,366,920,938,463,463,374,607,431,768,211,455`.

A small detail to mention is that when attempting to create the asset using the same ID, I can't input more then 10 numbers. (not sure how the asset id on Shiden and Astar is so long)

[image]

Also I attempted to create the asset with an arbitrirary id and then register the asset location from the `xcAssetConfig` pallet which points to the Relay Chain.

[image]

After which I attempted to execute the `reserveTransferAsset` call to transfer DOT from Relay Chain to Shiden. This failed with the error `!!! ERROR: TooExpensive` on the Parachain.

To my knowledge this has to do with not being able to pay for fees.

[image]

Here are the logs which include the error:

```
2023-10-24 17:48:31.504 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::weight: [Relaychain] FixedWeightBounds message: Xcm([SetFeesMode { jit_withdraw: true }, TransferReserveAsset { assets: MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }]), dest: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(Parachain(2000)) }, xcm: Xcm([]) }])    
2023-10-24 17:48:34.893  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain]  Idle (5 peers), best: #113 (0x4b34…004c), finalized #111 (0xc059…fd3e), ⬇ 6.8kiB/s ⬆ 12.8kiB/s    
2023-10-24 17:48:34.893  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain]  Idle (1 peers), best: #43 (0x38e1…1971), finalized #42 (0x6fd9…c069), ⬇ 73 B/s ⬆ 0.9kiB/s    
2023-10-24 17:48:36.022 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::weight: [Relaychain] FixedWeightBounds message: Xcm([SetFeesMode { jit_withdraw: true }, TransferReserveAsset { assets: MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }]), dest: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(Parachain(2000)) }, xcm: Xcm([]) }])    
2023-10-24 17:48:36.022 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::weight: [Relaychain] FixedWeightBounds message: Xcm([ReserveAssetDeposited(MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }])), ClearOrigin, BuyExecution { fees: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }, weight_limit: Limited(<wasm:stripped>) }, DepositAsset { assets: Wild(AllCounted(1)), beneficiary: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: None, id: [198, 12, 27, 199, 44, 231, 102, 68, 94, 238, 238, 100, 220, 113, 6, 27, 77, 255, 98, 111, 132, 246, 75, 41, 58, 31, 125, 42, 57, 14, 214, 96] }) } }])    
2023-10-24 17:48:36.022 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::weight: [Relaychain] FixedWeightBounds message: Xcm([SetFeesMode { jit_withdraw: true }, TransferReserveAsset { assets: MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }]), dest: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(Parachain(2000)) }, xcm: Xcm([BuyExecution { fees: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }, weight_limit: Limited(<wasm:stripped>) }, DepositAsset { assets: Wild(AllCounted(1)), beneficiary: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: None, id: [198, 12, 27, 199, 44, 231, 102, 68, 94, 238, 238, 100, 220, 113, 6, 27, 77, 255, 98, 111, 132, 246, 75, 41, 58, 31, 125, 42, 57, 14, 214, 96] }) } }]) }])    
2023-10-24 17:48:36.022 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::weight: [Relaychain] WeightInfoBounds message: Xcm([SetFeesMode { jit_withdraw: true }, TransferReserveAsset { assets: MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }]), dest: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(Parachain(2000)) }, xcm: Xcm([BuyExecution { fees: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }, weight_limit: Limited(<wasm:stripped>) }, DepositAsset { assets: Wild(AllCounted(1)), beneficiary: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: None, id: [198, 12, 27, 199, 44, 231, 102, 68, 94, 238, 238, 100, 220, 113, 6, 27, 77, 255, 98, 111, 132, 246, 75, 41, 58, 31, 125, 42, 57, 14, 214, 96] }) } }]) }])    
2023-10-24 17:48:36.022 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::execute_xcm_in_credit: [Relaychain] origin: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: Some(Kusama), id: [212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125] }) }, message: Xcm([SetFeesMode { jit_withdraw: true }, TransferReserveAsset { assets: MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }]), dest: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(Parachain(2000)) }, xcm: Xcm([BuyExecution { fees: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }, weight_limit: Limited(<wasm:stripped>) }, DepositAsset { assets: Wild(AllCounted(1)), beneficiary: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: None, id: [198, 12, 27, 199, 44, 231, 102, 68, 94, 238, 238, 100, 220, 113, 6, 27, 77, 255, 98, 111, 132, 246, 75, 41, 58, 31, 125, 42, 57, 14, 214, 96] }) } }]) }]), weight_credit: <wasm:stripped>    
2023-10-24 17:48:36.022 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::barriers: [Relaychain] TakeWeightCredit origin: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: Some(Kusama), id: [212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125] }) }, instructions: [SetFeesMode { jit_withdraw: true }, TransferReserveAsset { assets: MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }]), dest: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(Parachain(2000)) }, xcm: Xcm([BuyExecution { fees: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }, weight_limit: Limited(<wasm:stripped>) }, DepositAsset { assets: Wild(AllCounted(1)), beneficiary: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: None, id: [198, 12, 27, 199, 44, 231, 102, 68, 94, 238, 238, 100, 220, 113, 6, 27, 77, 255, 98, 111, 132, 246, 75, 41, 58, 31, 125, 42, 57, 14, 214, 96] }) } }]) }], max_weight: <wasm:stripped>, weight_credit: <wasm:stripped>    
2023-10-24 17:48:36.022 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::process: [Relaychain] origin: Some(MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: Some(Kusama), id: [212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125] }) }), total_surplus/refunded: <wasm:stripped>/<wasm:stripped>, error_handler_weight: <wasm:stripped>    
2023-10-24 17:48:36.022 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::process_instruction: [Relaychain] === SetFeesMode { jit_withdraw: true }    
2023-10-24 17:48:36.022 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::process_instruction: [Relaychain] === TransferReserveAsset { assets: MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }]), dest: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(Parachain(2000)) }, xcm: Xcm([BuyExecution { fees: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }, weight_limit: Limited(<wasm:stripped>) }, DepositAsset { assets: Wild(AllCounted(1)), beneficiary: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: None, id: [198, 12, 27, 199, 44, 231, 102, 68, 94, 238, 238, 100, 220, 113, 6, 27, 77, 255, 98, 111, 132, 246, 75, 41, 58, 31, 125, 42, 57, 14, 214, 96] }) } }]) }    
2023-10-24 17:48:36.022 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::currency_adapter: [Relaychain] internal_transfer_asset asset: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }, from: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: Some(Kusama), id: [212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125] }) }, to: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(Parachain(2000)) }    
2023-10-24 17:48:36.022 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::execute_xcm_in_credit: [Relaychain] result: Ok(())    
2023-10-24 17:48:36.024  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #114 (0xc2b2…76b1)    
2023-10-24 17:48:39.897  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain]  Idle (1 peers), best: #43 (0x38e1…1971), finalized #42 (0x6fd9…c069), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2023-10-24 17:48:39.897  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain]  Idle (5 peers), best: #114 (0xc2b2…76b1), finalized #111 (0xc059…fd3e), ⬇ 2.1kiB/s ⬆ 1.7kiB/s    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.027  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #115 (0x066c…ce33)    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.032  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #115 (0x6e15…70ef)    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.038  INFO tokio-runtime-worker cumulus-collator: [Parachain] Starting collation. relay_parent=0x066c52a364962c1215956dd6fdd51cad835d383a609a887f880647eb070ece33 at=0x38781c21a6375eb1b1a70f44837d5ac047cc6d68f614f8b5977b774f44740d34
2023-10-24 17:48:42.045  INFO tokio-runtime-worker cumulus-collator: [Parachain] Starting collation. relay_parent=0x6e15de40b8bbd48b82244d39dce7beec0816a138e26728e085da44b16a9070ef at=0x38781c21a6375eb1b1a70f44837d5ac047cc6d68f614f8b5977b774f44740d34
2023-10-24 17:48:42.132 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker xcm::execute_xcm: [Parachain] origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }, message: Xcm([ReserveAssetDeposited(MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }])), ClearOrigin, BuyExecution { fees: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }, weight_limit: Limited(<wasm:stripped>) }, DepositAsset { assets: Wild(AllCounted(1)), beneficiary: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: None, id: [198, 12, 27, 199, 44, 231, 102, 68, 94, 238, 238, 100, 220, 113, 6, 27, 77, 255, 98, 111, 132, 246, 75, 41, 58, 31, 125, 42, 57, 14, 214, 96] }) } }]), weight_limit: <wasm:stripped>    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.132 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::weight: [Parachain] FixedWeightBounds message: Xcm([ReserveAssetDeposited(MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }])), ClearOrigin, BuyExecution { fees: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }, weight_limit: Limited(<wasm:stripped>) }, DepositAsset { assets: Wild(AllCounted(1)), beneficiary: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: None, id: [198, 12, 27, 199, 44, 231, 102, 68, 94, 238, 238, 100, 220, 113, 6, 27, 77, 255, 98, 111, 132, 246, 75, 41, 58, 31, 125, 42, 57, 14, 214, 96] }) } }])    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.132 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::execute_xcm_in_credit: [Parachain] origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }, message: Xcm([ReserveAssetDeposited(MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }])), ClearOrigin, BuyExecution { fees: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }, weight_limit: Limited(<wasm:stripped>) }, DepositAsset { assets: Wild(AllCounted(1)), beneficiary: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: None, id: [198, 12, 27, 199, 44, 231, 102, 68, 94, 238, 238, 100, 220, 113, 6, 27, 77, 255, 98, 111, 132, 246, 75, 41, 58, 31, 125, 42, 57, 14, 214, 96] }) } }]), weight_credit: <wasm:stripped>    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.132 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::barriers: [Parachain] TakeWeightCredit origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }, instructions: [ReserveAssetDeposited(MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }])), ClearOrigin, BuyExecution { fees: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }, weight_limit: Limited(<wasm:stripped>) }, DepositAsset { assets: Wild(AllCounted(1)), beneficiary: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: None, id: [198, 12, 27, 199, 44, 231, 102, 68, 94, 238, 238, 100, 220, 113, 6, 27, 77, 255, 98, 111, 132, 246, 75, 41, 58, 31, 125, 42, 57, 14, 214, 96] }) } }], max_weight: <wasm:stripped>, weight_credit: <wasm:stripped>    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.132 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::barriers: [Parachain] AllowTopLevelPaidExecutionFrom origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }, instructions: [ReserveAssetDeposited(MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }])), ClearOrigin, BuyExecution { fees: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }, weight_limit: Limited(<wasm:stripped>) }, DepositAsset { assets: Wild(AllCounted(1)), beneficiary: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: None, id: [198, 12, 27, 199, 44, 231, 102, 68, 94, 238, 238, 100, 220, 113, 6, 27, 77, 255, 98, 111, 132, 246, 75, 41, 58, 31, 125, 42, 57, 14, 214, 96] }) } }], max_weight: <wasm:stripped>, weight_credit: <wasm:stripped>    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.132 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::process: [Parachain] origin: Some(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), total_surplus/refunded: <wasm:stripped>/<wasm:stripped>, error_handler_weight: <wasm:stripped>    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.132 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::process_instruction: [Parachain] === ReserveAssetDeposited(MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }]))    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.132 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::process_instruction: [Parachain] === ClearOrigin    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.132 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::process_instruction: [Parachain] === BuyExecution { fees: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }, weight_limit: Limited(<wasm:stripped>) }    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.132 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::weight: [Parachain] UsingComponents::buy_weight weight: <wasm:stripped>, payment: <wasm:stripped>    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.132 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::weight: [Parachain] FixedRateOfForeignAsset::buy_weight weight: <wasm:stripped>, payment: <wasm:stripped>    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.132 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::buy_weight: [Parachain] last_error: Some(TooExpensive), too_expensive_error_found: true    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.132 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::execute: [Parachain] !!! ERROR: TooExpensive    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.132 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::execute_xcm_in_credit: [Parachain] result: Err(ExecutorError { index: 2, xcm_error: TooExpensive, weight: <wasm:stripped> })    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.132 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::weight: [Parachain] UsingComponents::refund_weight weight: <wasm:stripped>    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.132 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::weight: [Parachain] FixedRateOfForeignAsset::refund_weight weight: <wasm:stripped>    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.132 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::execute_xcm_in_credit: [Parachain] Execution errored at 2: TooExpensive (original_origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here })    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.133  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain] ✨ Imported #45 (0xa336…1291)    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.156 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker xcm::execute_xcm: [Parachain] origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }, message: Xcm([ReserveAssetDeposited(MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }])), ClearOrigin, BuyExecution { fees: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }, weight_limit: Limited(<wasm:stripped>) }, DepositAsset { assets: Wild(AllCounted(1)), beneficiary: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: None, id: [198, 12, 27, 199, 44, 231, 102, 68, 94, 238, 238, 100, 220, 113, 6, 27, 77, 255, 98, 111, 132, 246, 75, 41, 58, 31, 125, 42, 57, 14, 214, 96] }) } }]), weight_limit: <wasm:stripped>    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.156 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::weight: [Parachain] FixedWeightBounds message: Xcm([ReserveAssetDeposited(MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }])), ClearOrigin, BuyExecution { fees: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }, weight_limit: Limited(<wasm:stripped>) }, DepositAsset { assets: Wild(AllCounted(1)), beneficiary: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: None, id: [198, 12, 27, 199, 44, 231, 102, 68, 94, 238, 238, 100, 220, 113, 6, 27, 77, 255, 98, 111, 132, 246, 75, 41, 58, 31, 125, 42, 57, 14, 214, 96] }) } }])    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.156 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::execute_xcm_in_credit: [Parachain] origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }, message: Xcm([ReserveAssetDeposited(MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }])), ClearOrigin, BuyExecution { fees: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }, weight_limit: Limited(<wasm:stripped>) }, DepositAsset { assets: Wild(AllCounted(1)), beneficiary: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: None, id: [198, 12, 27, 199, 44, 231, 102, 68, 94, 238, 238, 100, 220, 113, 6, 27, 77, 255, 98, 111, 132, 246, 75, 41, 58, 31, 125, 42, 57, 14, 214, 96] }) } }]), weight_credit: <wasm:stripped>    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.156 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::barriers: [Parachain] TakeWeightCredit origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }, instructions: [ReserveAssetDeposited(MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }])), ClearOrigin, BuyExecution { fees: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }, weight_limit: Limited(<wasm:stripped>) }, DepositAsset { assets: Wild(AllCounted(1)), beneficiary: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: None, id: [198, 12, 27, 199, 44, 231, 102, 68, 94, 238, 238, 100, 220, 113, 6, 27, 77, 255, 98, 111, 132, 246, 75, 41, 58, 31, 125, 42, 57, 14, 214, 96] }) } }], max_weight: <wasm:stripped>, weight_credit: <wasm:stripped>    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.156 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::barriers: [Parachain] AllowTopLevelPaidExecutionFrom origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }, instructions: [ReserveAssetDeposited(MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }])), ClearOrigin, BuyExecution { fees: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }, weight_limit: Limited(<wasm:stripped>) }, DepositAsset { assets: Wild(AllCounted(1)), beneficiary: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32 { network: None, id: [198, 12, 27, 199, 44, 231, 102, 68, 94, 238, 238, 100, 220, 113, 6, 27, 77, 255, 98, 111, 132, 246, 75, 41, 58, 31, 125, 42, 57, 14, 214, 96] }) } }], max_weight: <wasm:stripped>, weight_credit: <wasm:stripped>    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.156 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::process: [Parachain] origin: Some(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), total_surplus/refunded: <wasm:stripped>/<wasm:stripped>, error_handler_weight: <wasm:stripped>    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.156 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::process_instruction: [Parachain] === ReserveAssetDeposited(MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }]))    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.156 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::process_instruction: [Parachain] === ClearOrigin    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.156 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::process_instruction: [Parachain] === BuyExecution { fees: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(1000000000000000) }, weight_limit: Limited(<wasm:stripped>) }    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.156 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::weight: [Parachain] UsingComponents::buy_weight weight: <wasm:stripped>, payment: <wasm:stripped>    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.156 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::weight: [Parachain] FixedRateOfForeignAsset::buy_weight weight: <wasm:stripped>, payment: <wasm:stripped>    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.156 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::buy_weight: [Parachain] last_error: Some(TooExpensive), too_expensive_error_found: true    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.156 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::execute: [Parachain] !!! ERROR: TooExpensive    
2023-10-24 17:48:42.156 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::execute_xcm_in_credit: [Parachain] result: Err(ExecutorError { index: 2, xcm_error: TooExpensive, weight: <wasm:stripped> })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To my knowledge this has to do with not being able to pay for fees.

Yes. To configure any customized asset to pay XCM fees, you must set the fee payment *unit per second* with `xcAssetConfig.setAssetUnitsPerSecond`.

It depends on what you need for local setup, but in general, I would recommend using Chopsticks.